# Why is the title bar appearing behind the status bar after a rotation?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, rotation

I have a UIViewController whose view is a UIWebView with an embedded movie.  When the movie is playing full screen, and the device is rotated, the title bar ends up behind the status bar after the movie is dismissed.  Why might this happen?

[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Have you solved it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the animation of the view controller's view wasn't finished when the video started.  This caused it to be redisplayed over the video player view.

Comment: start the video after the animation completes

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=NO;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

did you autoresizingMask on the UIWebView

```
webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
```

and

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation 
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes.  The view that is behind the status bar is the UINavigationController's view.  It is autoloaded by the UINavigationController code.  Also, It doesn't happen when I rotate the device when the movie isn't playing.  When I rotate the device when it's in this "bad" state, it corrects itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's no way to resolve this problem using MPMoviePlayerNotification, because UIWebView Video Don't use MPMoviePlayerViewController or it's private for developer.
But, there's another way to fix this bug.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleStatusBarFrameDidChange)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void)handleStatusBarFrameDidChange {
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```